# Getting `Cannot read property 'byteLength' of undefined` when accessing AppSync with AWS_IAM authentication type

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql

I setup my backend using AWS Amplify, everything works using API_KEY but now I'm trying to use AWS_IAM but it's throwing me the error

I don't want to use AWS Cognito User pools because it won't allow unauth users to access my API

```
Amplify.configure({
  API: {
    "aws_project_region": "ap-southeast-1",
    "aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint": "endpoint",
    // "aws_appsync_authenticationType": "API_KEY",
    "aws_appsync_authenticationType": "AWS_IAM",
  },
  Auth: {
    identityPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_identityPoolId,
    region: process.env.REACT_APP_awsRegion,
    userPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_userPoolId,
    userPoolWebClientId: process.env.REACT_APP_userPoolAppClientId,
   },
  Storage: { 
    bucket: process.env.REACT_APP_bucketName,
    region: process.env.REACT_APP_awsRegion,
    identityPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_identityPoolId
   }
});
```

Comment: try adding `aws_appsync_region` instead of `aws_project_region `

Comment: And also u can configure UnAuth users also with the Cognito pools. Check the IAM policies

Comment: It has worked now thanks you so much @sandaru.ny!